# NoMethodError when trying to access Ruby hash, yet works in irb

Tags: ruby, hash

I am building a cash register in Ruby that has the following hash:

```
    @change = [
                  { :denomination => 0.01, :amount => 5 },
                  { :denomination => 0.02, :amount => 5 },
                  { :denomination => 0.05, :amount => 5 },
                  { :denomination => 0.10, :amount => 5 },
                  { :denomination => 0.20, :amount => 5 },
                  { :denomination => 0.50, :amount => 5 },
                  { :denomination => 1.00, :amount => 5 },
                  { :denomination => 2.00, :amount => 5 }
        ]
```

When a user makes a purchase, the coins they use are passed in as an argument in the form of an array.

```
    def pay(coins = [])
        coins.each do |coin|
          coin = @change.find { |x| x[:denomination] == coin }
          coin[:amount] += 1
        end
     end
```

This works fine when I manually test in irb from my terminal. However, when I try to run `rspec`, it fails with a NoMethodError:

```
 Failure/Error: coin[:amount] += 1

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I really cannot see why this is failing with a NoMethodError, especially as it runs fine in the terminal. Can anyone please help?

Thanks :)

UPDATE:

Spec for this:

```
describe '#pay' do
    it 'updates the change' do
      till.pay([0.5])
      expect(till.change).to include(:denomination=>0.5, :amount=>6)
    end
  end
```

Comment: What's the code in your spec?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I have updated to add in the spec :)

Comment: In `pay`, the coin argument is an array of floats, a float does not implement the `[]` method, hence your error. Can you explain further what you're trying to do, in order to get a better understanding and a better answer?

Comment: I see, but how come it works when I feature test this in my terminal, seems odd? 

Sure - when a user pays with coins for an item (50p coin in this example, which is the 0.5), I want this to be added to the money already in the cash register (the first hash). Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, the last comment wasn't really the problem, I confused the error since the coin shadowing variable within each. Take a look at the answer provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes when invoking [] in a `nil` object.

When you pass a denomination that's not in your `@change` instance variable, the result of `@change.find { ... }` will be `nil`, and invoking `[]` in a `nil` object will raise a NoMethodError.

That's a case you haven't covered, and that might be solved by using `next` within the `each` enumerator:

```
coins.each do |coin|
  current_denomination = @change.find { |x| x[:denomination] == coin }
  next unless current_denomination

  current_denomination[:amount] += 1
end

p pay([0.05, 0.05, 2.0, 100])
```

In case there's no change with the same coin and denomination, you just "jump" to the next element within coins.

Notice the current implementation of `@change` allows you to repeat the hashes within the array, which can lead to errors if a denomination differs with its initial value of amount. You can just use a Hash to store both, denomination and amount as key-value:

```
p [0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0].to_h { |a| [a, 5] }
# {0.01=>5, 0.02=>5, 0.05=>5, 0.1=>5, 0.2=>5, 0.5=>5, 1.0=>5, 2.0=>5}
```

That's Ruby 2.6+.

---

As a minor tweak to your implementation, you can move `@change` to a separate method, which you can call and use then by invoking `tap` on it:

```
DENOMINATIONS = [0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0].freeze
HASH_KEYS = %i[denomination amount].freeze

def initial_coins
  DENOMINATIONS.zip(Array.new(8, 5)).map { |coin| HASH_KEYS.zip(coin).to_h }
end

def pay(coins = [])
  initial_coins.tap do |this|
    coins.each do |coin|
      current_denomination = this.find { |initial_coin| initial_coin[:denomination] == coin }
      next unless current_denomination

      current_denomination[:amount] += 1
    end
  end
end

pp pay([0.05, 0.05, 2.0, 100])
# [{:denomination=>0.01, :amount=>5},
#  {:denomination=>0.02, :amount=>5},
#  {:denomination=>0.05, :amount=>7},
#  {:denomination=>0.1, :amount=>5},
#  {:denomination=>0.2, :amount=>5},
#  {:denomination=>0.5, :amount=>5},
#  {:denomination=>1.0, :amount=>5},
#  {:denomination=>2.0, :amount=>6}]
```